# Why does this switch statement give 11 as the output?

Tags: c

I help teach an intro to computer science course in a university, and the professor I help gives me tests before the students, to make sure that I don't think the questions are too hard or confusing. He gave me one problem with the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
  int x = 5;

  switch(x){
    case 3: x += 1;
    case 4: x += 2;
    case 5: x += 3;
    case 6: x++;
    case 7: x += 2;
    case 8: x--;
    case 9: x++;
  }
}
```

Now when I run it, I thought the output should be 10. However, when run, it outputs 11. I put print statements after each case, and the output looked like this:

```
8
9
11
10
11
11
```

So my question is, can someone explain this? I feel like it's some simple thing but I cannot figure it out for the life of me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `switch` starts at `case 5` and falls through (because the lack of the `break`-keyword) until the end. So: 5 + 3 + 1 + 2 - 1 + 1 = 11

Comment: I can't believe I missed this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In C programming language not every case contains a break. If no break appears, the flow of control will fall through to cases until a break is reached.

Therefor if x starts as 5

```
case 5: x += 3;  //5+3 = 8
case 6: x++;     //8+1 = 9
case 7: x += 2;  //9+2 = 11
case 8: x--;    //11-1 = 10
case 9: x++;    //10+1 = 11
```

And the result is 11.